# Building GitHub user pages with travis ci

Tags: git, github, gruntjs, travis-ci, github-pages

I have a github page https://sarathsnair.github.io and I want to add continuous integration using `travis ci`. My need is use to `grunt/gulp` to run tasks such as minification, concatenation etc before deploying to `master` branch. By default, GitHub USER/ORGANIZATION page use source as `master` branch and GitHub PROJECT pages uses `gh-pages/docs folder/master` etc. I saw tutorials on integrating travis with GitHub PROJECET pages such as

- https://gist.github.com/domenic/ec8b0fc8ab45f39403dd
- https://voorhoede.github.io/front-end-tooling-recipes/travis-deploy-to-gh-pages/

But I couldn't see any tutorials based on GitHub user pages. So basically this is what I am trying to do

1. Currently, development is happening on `master` branch. I don't have any other branches.
2. When I commit on my local `master` branch and push to remote `master`, a build should trigger automatically on travis ci which should do the following things.
3. Minify all the `JavaScript` files and combine.
4. Minify all the `css` files and concatenate.
5. Minify `HTML` files and combine them.
6. These files are deployed on `master` branch and deliver it when user see my page (*not the actual development files*).

I am very new to travis ci, so confused with GitHub PROJECT page configuration and USER page configuration in travis. I did the following things as of now.

1. Site development is getting completed. I am not using jekyl or any such tools. I use basic HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It can be accessed at http://sarathsnair.me
2. Created travis account
3. Enabled travis ci for my repo (https://github.com/sarathsnair/sarathsnair.github.io)
4. Gnerated GitHub token and added in travis settings.

I am stuck at creation of `.travis.yml` and `deploy.sh` script. Can someone help me on this.